# Why does Hilt @Bind construct a class multiple times? And what is the best practice way of listening to network in a repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, dagger-hilt, kotlin-stateflow

**The Questions**:

1. Could you please suggest a best practice way of getting network connectivity status in a repository that needs to determine from where to fetch data. My min Api is 23.
2. Why does Hilt construct the class multiple times even if it's supposed to be installed in SingletonComponent?

I have borrowed from a Medium article and built a `NetworkStatusManager`. It is injected into my `DetailsRepository` with Hilt through `@Binds`. This `NetworkStatusManager` emits a flow when network becomes available or unavailable. I want to use that flow in repository and have an always up-to-date status of connectivity so `DetailsRepository` can determine where to fetch data (locally or remotely).

I've seen many examples of how people use these `NetworkCallback`s in `ViewModel`s, but to me it doesn't make sense to use them there. `ViewModel` shouldn't know where data comes from. Repository determines which data to provide, but to do that, it must know if internet is available to know where to get data from. I also want, in case of failure, to return a `ResultOf` that will have a `NoInternetException` so THEN `ViewModel` will get to provide an appropriate error message to UI.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
class DetailsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
     private val networkStatusManager: NetworkStatusManager,
     @IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : DetailsRepository {

private var mNetwork : Boolean = false
val networkStatus : StateFlow<NetworkStatus> = networkStatusManager.networkStatus
    .flowOn(dispatcher)
    .onEach {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON EACH: networkStatus received = ${it.toString()}")
        mNetwork = when (it) {
            NetworkStatus.Available -> true
            NetworkStatus.Unavailable -> false
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "ON EACH: Current mNetwork value is : $mNetwork")
}.stateIn(
    CoroutineScope(dispatcher),
    SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    initialValue = NetworkStatus.Unavailable
)
...
}
```

Now in the same repository I have a method `getTitle` that checks that `mNetwork` value. For interest's sake I also check the `networkStatus.value`:

```
override suspend fun getTitle(mediaId: Long, type: TitleType): ResultOf<Title> =
    withContext(dispatcher) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getTitle: LAUNCHED GET TITLE")
        Log.d(TAG, "getTitle: networkStatus = ${networkStatus.value}")

        Log.d(TAG, "getTitle: mNetwork = ${mNetwork}")

        // when (mNetwork) {
        //     This is where I would determine what to do next based on connectivity
        // }
        Log.d(TAG, "getTitle: NETWORK CHECK DONE")
...
}
```

**The problem**:
This repository is injected with @Binds by Hilt to some viewmodel. The `networkStatus` then get's triggered and the `mNetwork` gets set correctly. BUT, then I click on a movie, this is where `DetailsRepository` has to actually start providing data, and the `DetailsRepository` gets AGAIN constructed?? (I checked, init block gets launched again) and then the `getTitle` method gets called, but at that time the `mNetwork` value is "new" and is equal to false.

**Other solution I've tried:**
Simply accessing the `networkStatusManager.networkStatus` `first()` operator and just getting the current value of the network status, but if the app starts with no connectivity available then this line freezes seemingly indefinetly:

```
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkStatusCallback)
```

This is how NetworkStatusManager and DetailsRepository are bound:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AbstractionsModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDetailsRepository(detailsRepositoryImpl: DetailsRepositoryImpl): DetailsRepository

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNetworkStatusManager(networkStatusManagerImpl: NetworkStatusManagerImpl): NetworkStatusManager
    ...
}
```

My Logcat showing the values of `DetailsRepository`. In the red block you can see that NetworkStatusManager emitted `Available` value, `DetailsRepository` received it in onEach and `mNetwork` was set. Then after 5 seconds I clicked on a Movie, it led to `DetailsScreen` and the `DetailsViewmodel` seemingly constructed the `DetailsRepository` AGAIN, because you can that first the `getTitle` method gets called, it checks the `mNetwork` value which is false by default and ONLY THEN `NetworkStatusManager` emits a value again and then my StateFlow in `DetailsRepository` gets it and changes `mNetwork` but at that point it's too late :)
If it's installed in the SingletonComponent, shouldn't it be the same `DetailsRepository`?

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4tl.png)

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: Not really... I ended up using two things. For data layer: repositories, datasources etc. I just have a ConnectivityChecker class that checks for connectivity on the spot, but it has to be called each time. 2) I copied and used the approach from Now in Android app (it's available on GitHub) and I listen to connectivity changes in the ui layer and show appropriate errors and/or snackbars from there.